# Ограничение действия привилегии

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory

Есть ли какой-то стандартный способ выдать пользователю или группе пользователей домена некоторую привилегию, например "Вход в качестве службы". И ограничить ее действие одним или несколькими компьютерами?

Вариант выдавать привилегию в локальных политиках конкретного компьютера доменным пользователям не рассматривается.

Интересует любое решение: MMC консоль, PowerShell, API.

Если это принципиально невозможно для произвольной привилегии, то, может, есть какие-то специальные привилегии, которое это позволяют делать?

Comment: Ну 2 варианта. 1-й: кидаем компы в группу, gpo применяем только на эту группу, а не на "прошедшие проверку". 2-й: кидаем политику в отдельный OU, и докидываем туда эти компы.

Я же правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос понят правильно. Только я почти Не понял ответа. Если компы сложить в группу и применить политику к этой группе компьютеров, то тогда как разрулить их по разным пользователям? Идея такая есть привилегия нужно ее выдать пользователю1 для работы с компьютером1 и пользователю2 для работы с компьютером2. Пользователь1 на компьютере2 таких прав иметь не должен

Comment: Я не администратор, я программист и мне нужно в своей программе рашить проблему авторизации (аутентификацию уже сделал)

Comment: Я не гуру AD\GPO, но тогда на одну машину+пользователя - одну gpo. Конечную реализацию могу кинуть позже, когда будет более удобный способ доступа до рабочих серваков.

Comment: Бросьте, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак. Алгоритм следующий

1. В оснастке `Active Directory - пользователи и компьютеры` где-то в дереве создаем новое подразделение (Depatment)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Далее кликаем по нужному компьютеру и перемещаем его в созданное подразделение

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Заходим в свойства созданного подразделения, выбираем вкладку групповые политики и жмем `Открыть`

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. В появившемся окне создаем новую групповую политику и открываем ее на редактирование

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Далее мы **переопределяем** те политики которые нас интересуют.

После этого все компьютеры в этом подразделении и под-подразделениях получают нашу политику

Comment: На вкладке "делегирование" не забудь добавить "Компьютеры домена", а то не поедет.